# Fetching data from database (CoreData)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uimanageddocument

I have two questions:

1- Do i need to have the same UImanagedDocument to enter entities and fetch them, or is it possible to enter and read the data from different objects?

2- Is there any way to confirm that data has been entered to the database? (except for fetching the data)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You really want to spend some time with core data itself - `UIManagedDocument` is just a thin API wrapper over the core data stack. This is a good book on the subject, definitely worth the cost: [Core Data (2nd edition): Data Storage and Management...](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data)

2) You can get an app like [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) and open the `persistentStore` file. It will take some deciphering as to how core data stores stuff in the database but you can see it in there.

Again because `UIManagedDocument` relies so heavily on core data I would recommend spending the time learning it well. Core data has some interesting complexities at times.